# Convert from .jks to passwordless .p12?

Tags: key, pkcs#12, jks

I have a java key store that contains a cert and private key. I want to convert this to a .p12 file that has no password. I'm using the .p12 in a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use keytool to convert from JKS to PKCS12.  I would bet that you would be forced to give a password, however, for constructing the PKCS12

From there, I'd look into tools (?OpenSSL?), that will let you manipulate the PKCS12 to remove the password.  Then you're in the world of 100% PKCS12, so you have more of a range of tools to choose from.

My only quandary is whether it's possible to have a PKCS12 without a password.  Since this is the private key we're talking about, pretty much every standard agrees that a password is a bare minimum.  The security purist would ask - "if you have to remove all protections on the private key, why use the private key at all?"